# Notification about object method invocation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is there a way in objective-c to find out if a method of an object has been invoked, by lets say something similar to KVO?

I have tracking code that always needs to go inside viewDidAppear and viewDidDissapear.
I would like to be notified when any of those methods has been called so I can either start tracking or stop tracking an object out side of those two methods.

You could probably say why would I need it if I could just call my tracking code inside those two methods... Well I want to take this hassel from the users and automate the tracking process.

**EDIT**

This is what is currently going on:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.view trackWithKey:@"Unique UI Element key"];
    //...
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.view stopTracking];
    //...
}
```

This is what I would like to do:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   [tracker.trackWithKey:@"xxxxxx"];
}
```

The `tracker` object would listen on its parents `ViewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` method invocations, so when they are fired it would either call start or stop tracking.

Comment: This question is missing some necessary information; it's not clear [what you're up to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Are you developing a library? If so, what's the overall design? If not, then what users are you talking about? As always, [sample code](http://sscce.org/) is king.

Comment: Please view my edit in the question, I added some code to explain what I am looking for.

Comment: the update doesn't address my comment. This question still suffers from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google for "Method Swizzling". Understand it completely. That should help you solve your problem.